# Download kaggle package on aws sagemaker notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, kaggle

I want to download the kaggle package in my aws notebook (sagemaker on aws).
this is the original code:

```
# Download the data:
api_token = {"username":"....","key":"..."}
!sudo mkdir -p /root/.kaggle
with open('/root/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
  json.dump(api_token, file)
!chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle competitions download -c filename  -p "./"
```

The data is very big (30gb) so this is the only way to download it fast.
this line is giving me problem beacuse of premissions:

```
with open('/root/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
  json.dump(api_token, file)
```

error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.kaggle/kaggle.json'
```

What can I do?

Comment: You need to specify a local folder in the SageMaker notebook instance. Something line '~/.' or any other folder that you can create from the terminal on the instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download Kaggle datasets in the AWS Sagemaker Notebook instance you can follow the following steps :

1. Generate API key in Kaggle web UI
2. Upload it to your root folder (i.e.  /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/ ) via the web interface
3. In the terminal (of Jupyter lab), use the following commands

`pip install kaggle`

`mkdir /home/ec2-user/.kaggle`

`mv /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/kaggle.json /home/ec2-user/.kaggle`

`kaggle datasets download -d  name_of_the_dataset`

reference: https://freddiek.github.io/2018/06/10/accessing-Kaggle-from-SageMaker-instance.html